# JIRA Backup downgrade

Tags: backup, jira

I need to import a backup of higher JIRA Version.

Is it possible to downgrade a backup of a higher JIRA version to be able to import it?

Comment: @Mike Miller, because the jira live version is higher then jira version that I use for testing some plugins that I'm developing. But now I found that you can use the same license for another Jira for non-production use. So the problem is solved.

Comment: Cool, they made the licensing page on their website much easier to use in more recent versions. You can always generate 2 month trial licenses with your account as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible!
Solution: upgrade Jira version